# The navbar menu doesn't vertically aligned on small screen and the position of hamburger menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

My top menu and submenu look fine on normal screen. When shrunk in smaller size, I would expect menus/submenus to be aligned vertically as normal dropdowns by bootstrap. This doesn't happen as shown below. How can I show the dropdown list(menus and submenus) vertically aligned on small screen?

TIA

Screenshots
[image]
[image]

Code

```
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark ">
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menubar">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="navbar-collapse" id="menubar">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item ">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="#">Menu1</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu2</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu1</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu2</a></li>
                                
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Menu3</a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu3</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Submenu4</a></li>
                              
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>

 @media (max-width: 767px) {
    .navbar-collapse {
        background-color: #565149;
    }
    .banner-navbar,
    .banner-search {
        display: none;
    }
}
#menubar ul {
    height: 44px;
    padding-top: 5px;
}
#menubar .nav-link {
    font-size: 14px;
    padding: 8px 50px 0 0 !important;
    color: white !important;
}
    #menubar .nav-link:focus,
    #menubar .nav-link:hover,
    #menubar .nav-link:visited {
        color: white !important;
    }
    #menubar .navbar{
        padding-left: 0 !important;
    }
.navbar.navbar-dark {
    height: 44px; 
    margin: 0 15%;
}

nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item.active:after{
    content: "";
    position: relative;
    margin-left: -31px;
    left: 50%;
    bottom: 15px;
    border-left: 6px solid transparent;
    border-right: 6px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 6px solid white;
}
/*submenu*/
#menubar li.dropdown.show {
    position: static;
}
    #menubar li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

.dropdown-menu > li {
    display: table-cell;
    padding-top: 6px;
}
.dropdown-menu > li a{
    font-weight:600;
}
    .dropdown-menu > li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
```

Update:
Slightly modified from Rich's solution. Two problems for me:

1. somehow, the search box and the right after small navbar are too close to the middle of the screen. The should float to the right.
2. the input for search key words should double its width(more or less), but I don't want to give it a fixed pixel. How can I do this?
   Thanks

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .open > ul {
        display: inline-flex !important;
    }

    .bg-banner {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#17517f, #46769d);
    }

    .bg-headbar {
        background-color: #005db9;
    }

    #menubar .nav-link {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        color: white;
    }

    nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item.active:after {
        content: "";
        position: relative;
        margin-left: -31px;
        left: 50%;
        bottom: 15px;
        border-left: 6px solid transparent;
        border-right: 6px solid transparent;
        border-bottom: 6px solid white;
    }
   #menubar li.dropdown.show {
        position: static;
    }
    #menubar li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

    .dropdown-menu > li {
        display: table-cell;
        padding-top: 6px;
    }

        .dropdown-menu > li a {
            font-weight: 600;
        }

            .dropdown-menu > li a:hover {
                text-decoration: none;
            }
</style>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 .m-md-0 ml-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Seach">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-navbar collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-2"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Help</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-headbar py-0 py-8-md">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent" id="menubar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu1
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu2
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu3
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, blanditiis eaque? Vero consequuntur tempora vitae at maxime, repellendus excepturi quia quibusdam odit sed ullam praesentium natus rerum molestiae cupiditate possimus?
</p>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#menubar li.dropdown").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active show");
    },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active show");
        });
    $("#menubar ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#menubar li.dropdown").removeClass("active show");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn’t  have to do anything as the `navbar-nav ul` is normally set to `flex-direction: column` for small screens and it’s switched to `flex-direction: row` at the breakpoint set in the navbar (`.navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav`).

You didn’t provide a working version of your code via the Stackoverflow snippet tool, and I couldn’t easily get your code to run locally, so it’s not clear why you code isn’t doing what you want.

I did put together an alternate version of your code that may help you along. I’m not sure what you’re thinking for how to indicate to the user where they are via an `active` class, but that should be easy to add.

### Update

I've modified my answer to include your using JavaScript to add `active show` to display the dropdown menus and I shifted the small menu towards the right.

I fixed a problem for the ARIA labeling that was in my original version. I had duplicated the code, but neglected to give the ARIA labels a unique ID.

### Update 2

To prevent the content from shifting down every time the user hovers over the menubar, you could add a negative top margin to the content to move it up the same amount the menubar expands. The menubar would need a z-index value to move it over the content.

```js
$("#menubar li.dropdown").hover(function () {
    $(this).addClass("active show");
    $("#firstContent").addClass("mt-n15");
},
    function () {
        $(this).removeClass("active show");
        $("#firstContent").removeClass("mt-n15");
    });
$("#menubar ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").on("click", function (e) {
    $("#menubar li.dropdown").removeClass("active show");
    $("#firstContent").removeClass("mt-n15");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .open>ul { /* mine */
        display: inline-flex !important;
    }

    .bg-banner { /* mine */
        background-image: linear-gradient(#17517f, #46769d);
    }

    .bg-headbar { /* mine */
        background-color: #005db9;
    }

    #menubar .nav-link {
        font-size: 14px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        color: white;
    }

    @media (min-width:768px) {
        nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item.active:after {
            content: "";
            position: relative;
            margin-left: -31px;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 15px;
            border-left: 6px solid transparent;
            border-right: 6px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 6px solid white;
        }
    }

    #menubar li.dropdown.show {
        position: static;
    }

    #menubar li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }

    .dropdown-menu>li {
        display: table-cell;
        padding-top: 6px;
    }

    .dropdown-menu>li a {
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .dropdown-menu>li a:hover {
        text-decoration: none;
    }
    
    .mt-n15 {
        margin-top: -1.5rem;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSearchContent navbarHelpContent menubar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent" id="navbarSearchContent">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 .m-md-0 ml-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Seach" size="40">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-navbar collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 navbarSupportedContent" id="navbarHelpContent">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link pl-2"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Help</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-headbar py-0 py-8-md" style="z-index: 1;">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbarSupportedContent" id="menubar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu1
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu2
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu3
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div id="firstContent" class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, blanditiis eaque? Vero consequuntur tempora vitae at maxime, repellendus excepturi quia quibusdam odit sed ullam praesentium natus rerum molestiae cupiditate possimus?
        </div>
        <div class="col-12 col-sm-6">
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, blanditiis eaque? Vero consequuntur tempora vitae at maxime, repellendus excepturi quia quibusdam odit sed ullam praesentium natus rerum molestiae cupiditate possimus?
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. I was on something else will try your suggestion soon.

Comment: just updated my original question. Thanks!

Comment: Fantastic! Thanks for the help!

Comment: a favor to ask. When adding triangle pointer during hover, how can I keep the height of menu bar without expand?

Comment: With a pointer, there has to be more height. You could make the navbar taller all the time by defining the height to be 3.8125rem and adding `align-self-start` to the `#menubar` so it stays at the top. If you’re trying to stop the content from moving when a submenu is open, you could move the content up the same amt as the pointer expands the menubar (1.5rem). I’ve modified my answer so the menu expands but the content stays in the same position. *One additional consideration – your hover scheme won’t work for tablet users – you may want to use a click to open the submenus rather than hover.*

Comment: the Update 2 still expands(adding extra menubar height), The height can be larger but should be fixed. The triangle should touch the border of the menubar at very bottom(will adjust that once I got the solution of height). I was thinking I should give it an actual height with pixels, then change the style/css on shrinked screen. but not sure about it. And thanks for the hint on tablet.

Comment: I created another question about this here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67236466/navbar-with-custom-pointer-fixed-height . so the correct answer can be acknowledged.