# Navbar with custom pointer fixed height

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have created a test page with a menubar having a triangle pointer while hovering. All rest look fine except the blue menu bar expends its height when adding the pointer "at" the bottom of the bar. I can think of an approach that gives the menubar fixed height and remove this style during media query.

Is there a better/simple solution to add the pointer without changing the height?

(the triangle should touch the border of the menubar at the very bottom without gap. I'm going to adjust this after the solution of height)

TIA

Screenshot:
[image]
Code:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .bg-banner {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#17517f, #46769d);
    }

    .bg-headbar {
        background-color: #005db9;
    }

    .bg-banner .nav-link {
        color: white !important;
    }

    #menubar .nav-link {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        color: white;
    }
        #menubar .nav-link:focus,
        #menubar .nav-link:hover,
        #menubar .nav-link:visited {
            color: white;
        }
    @media (min-width:768px) {
        nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item.active:after {
            content: "";
            position: relative;
            margin-left: -31px;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 15px;
            border-left: 6px solid transparent;
            border-right: 6px solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 6px solid white;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width:767px) {
        .dropdown-menu > a {
            display: block !important;
        }
    }

    #menubar li.dropdown.show {
        position: static;
    }

        #menubar li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
            display: table;
            width: 100%;
            text-align: center;
            left: 0;
            right: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

    .dropdown-menu > a {
        display: table-cell;
    }

    .dropdown-menu > a {
        font-weight: 600;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-toggle">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggle">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 .m-md-0 ml-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Seach" size="40">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-navbar collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 navbar-toggle">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Help</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-headbar py-0 py-8-md">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggle" id="menubar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu1
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu2
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu3
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, blanditiis eaque? Vero consequuntur tempora vitae at maxime, repellendus excepturi quia quibusdam odit sed ullam praesentium natus rerum molestiae cupiditate possimus?
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#menubar li.dropdown").hover(function () {
        $(this).addClass("active show");
    },
        function () {
            $(this).removeClass("active show");
        });
    $("#menubar ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").on("click", function (e) {
        $("#menubar li.dropdown").removeClass("active show");
    });
</script>
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Ljrc0kgp/)

Comment: It looks like there is no triangle on hover, could you create [a jsfiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: @StepUp added jsfiddle

Comment: Can't you make the :after arrow an absolute item to the button you want to hover ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like @joshmoto's solution as it aligns the submenus directly under the menu item, but I think you can get the submenus to go full width if you apply `position: static` to the Menu1, etc. list items.

If you have the submenus going full width, then you’ll need to position the submenu towards the right to get things to line up (and you’ll need to adjust the values based on your menu text).

```js
$("#menubar li.dropdown").hover(function() {
        $(this).addClass("active show");
    },
    function() {
        $(this).removeClass("active show");
    });
$("#menubar ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#menubar li.dropdown").removeClass("active show");
});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .bg-banner {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#17517f, #46769d);
    }

    .bg-headbar {
        background-color: #005db9;
    }

    .bg-banner .nav-link {
        color: white !important;
    }

    #menubar .nav-link {
        font-size: 16px;
        padding-right: 50px;
        color: white;
    }

    #menubar .nav-link:focus,
    #menubar .nav-link:hover,
    #menubar .nav-link:visited {
        color: white;
    }

    @media (min-width:768px) {
        .navbar {
            height: 2.5rem;
        }

        nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item.active:after {
            content: "";
            position: relative;
            display: inline-block;
            margin-left: -1.6875rem;
            left: 50%;
            bottom: 1.1875rem;
            border-left: 0.375rem solid transparent;
            border-right: 0.375rem solid transparent;
            border-bottom: 0.375rem solid white;
        }

        .navbar-nav li:nth-child(2) .dropdown-menu {
            padding-left: 6.75rem;
        }

        .navbar-nav li:nth-child(3) .dropdown-menu {
            padding-left: 13.4375rem;
        }


        .dropdown-menu>a {
            font-weight: 600;
            float: left;
            width: auto;
            clear: none;
        }
    }

    @media (max-width:767px) {
        .dropdown-menu>a {
            display: block !important;
            font-weight: 600;
        }
    }

    #menubar li.dropdown.show {
        position: static;
    }

    #menubar li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        text-align: center;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        margin: 0;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-toggle">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggle">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 .m-md-0 ml-auto">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Seach" size="40">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <div class="banner-navbar collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 navbar-toggle">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Help</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>

</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-headbar py-0 py-8-md">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggle align-self-start" id="menubar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu1
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu2
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu3
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, blanditiis eaque? Vero consequuntur tempora vitae at maxime, repellendus excepturi quia quibusdam odit sed ullam praesentium natus rerum molestiae cupiditate possimus?
</div>
```

As you don't have the `dropdown-toggle` class on the menu1, etc. items, they will not open if a user is using the tab key to negotiate your site, plus the submenus don't work correctly with a touch device. If you don't need tab or touch support, then it should be okay.

Comment: Works perfectly. Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 1):

I see you are trying to add a triangle pointer for each hoverable nav item, i've not given you the perfect solution, i've only used your css and added a few tweeks to position the pseudo 'after' emel to it's parent as relative, not static.

My changes undo the full width active nav dropdown menu but this may get you on the right track

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<style>
  .bg-banner {
    background-image: linear-gradient(#17517f, #46769d);
  }
  
  .bg-headbar {
    background-color: #005db9;
  }
  
  .bg-banner .nav-link {
    color: white !important;
  }
  
  nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #menubar .nav-link {
    font-size: 16px;
    padding-right: 50px;
    color: white;
  }
  
  #menubar .nav-link:focus,
  #menubar .nav-link:hover,
  #menubar .nav-link:visited {
    color: white;
  }
  
  @media (min-width:768px) {
    nav.navbar .navbar-nav li.nav-item.active:after {
      content: "";
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: -31px;
      left: 50%;
      bottom: -1px;
      border-left: 6px solid transparent;
      border-right: 6px solid transparent;
      border-bottom: 6px solid white;
      z-index: 1001;
    }
  }
  
  @media (max-width:767px) {
    .dropdown-menu>a {
      display: block !important;
    }
  }
  
  #menubar li.dropdown.show {
    position: relative;
  }
  
  #menubar li.dropdown.show .dropdown-menu {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu>a {
    display: table-cell;
  }
  
  .dropdown-menu>a {
    font-weight: 600;
  }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-banner">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Test Site</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-toggle">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggle">
    <form class="form-inline my-2 .m-md-0 ml-auto">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Seach" size="40">
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div class="banner-navbar collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 navbar-toggle">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-sm navbar-light">
      <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-user"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
          </div>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a href="#" class="nav-link"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
          <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
            <i class="fa fa-question-circle"></i>
          </a>
          <div class="dropdown-menu">
            <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Help</a>

          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </div>

</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-headbar py-0 py-8-md">
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggle" id="menubar">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu1
                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1B</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu2
                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2A</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2B</a>
        </div>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item dropdown">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu3
                </a>
        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3A</a>
          <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3B</a>
        </div>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, blanditiis eaque? Vero consequuntur tempora vitae at maxime, repellendus excepturi quia quibusdam odit sed ullam praesentium natus rerum molestiae cupiditate possimus?
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $("#menubar li.dropdown").hover(function() {
      $(this).addClass("active show");
    },
    function() {
      $(this).removeClass("active show");
    });
  $("#menubar ul.dropdown-menu>li>a").on("click", function(e) {
    $("#menubar li.dropdown").removeClass("active show");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there still a way we can make submenu bar 100% width?

Answer (score 0):

For comparison, here's a navbar setup using the standard Bootstrap configuration. You don't get the hover effect, but it should work with the tab key and touch devices.

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>

<style>
    .bg-banner {
        background-image: linear-gradient(#17517f, #46769d);
    }

    .bg-headbar {
        background-color: #005db9;
    }
</style>

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-banner">
    <a class="navbar-brand mr-auto" href="#">Test Site</a>
    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-toggle">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 navbar-toggle">
        <form class="form-inline my-2 my-md-0 mr-md-3">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control form-control-sm" placeholder="Seach" size="40">
                <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-light btn-sm" type="button"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>

    <!--<div class="banner-navbar collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 navbar-toggle">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand navbar-light">-->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse flex-grow-0 navbar-toggle">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#" title="Sign Out">
                        <i class="fa fa-user text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign Out</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a href="#" class="nav-link" title="Setup"><i class="fa fa-cog text-white"></i></a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link" title="Help" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" href="#">
                        <i class="fa fa-question-circle text-white"></i>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Help</a>

                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark text-white bg-headbar py-0">
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-toggle align-self-start" id="menubar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
            <li class="nav-item dropdown active">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu1
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown1">
                    <a class="dropdown-item active" href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"> (current)</span></a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 1B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown2" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu2
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown2">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 2B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown3" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                    Menu3
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown3">
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3A</a>
                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Submenu 3B</a>
                </div>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Beatae, blanditiis eaque? Vero consequuntur tempora vitae at maxime, repellendus excepturi quia quibusdam odit sed ullam praesentium natus rerum molestiae cupiditate possimus?
</div>
```